# WebRTC Flutter - Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webrtc, agora.io

I have a chatbot application with tts and stt features. The microphone is active when the bot responds, that is, when the speech sound comes from the speaker. I don't want the microphone to detect the sound coming from the speaker. I only want it to detect the sound coming from the user. So I need parsed 16bit pcm audio data.

I use the WebRTC package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc for Flutter.

I need to use WebRTC because I need features like noise cancellation.

I want to get only audio data during the call, just like getting 8-16bit pcm audio data while listening on the microphone. For example https://pub.dev/packages/mic_stream

I need to access the media stream from the device with _localStream. But I'm not sure how to access audio files.
Here is the code I tried,

```
    // get localStream
   _localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
     'audio': isAudioOn,
     'video': isVideoOn
         ? {'facingMode': isFrontCameraSelected ? 'user' : 'environment'}
         : false,
   });

   // add mediaTrack to peerConnection
   _localStream!.getTracks().forEach((track) {
     _rtcPeerConnection!.addTrack(track, _localStream!);

     print(track.kind!.runes);
     print(track.kind!.codeUnits);
   });
```